# Свойство __proto__ — это геттер/сеттер

Tags: javascript, get, set

Подскажите,как понять, что `__proto__` - это геттер и сеттер. `obj.__proto__` вызывается соответствующий геттер/сеттер из прототипа obj. Какая механика этого процесса, никак не пойму этот принцип.

`__proto__` - свойство, которое дает доступ к методам объекта прототипа, а как оно работает как аксессор в прототипе?

Comment: я не понял вопрос. О какой механике идет речь? Плюс это свойство deprecated - не используй его

Comment: __proto__   - это геттер и сеттер в прототипе объекта. т.е Object.prototype.get __proto__: function set __proto__: function. Как именно __proto__ работает как аксессор.

Comment: Ты скопировал первый абзац из вопроса - но понятнее о чем именно ты спрашиваешь - не стало. Вопрос в том, как работает `obj.__proto__ = a`?  или в чем?

Comment: Не понятно почему __proto__ - это геттер и сеттер)) . Опишите Ваш пример пожалуйста.

Comment: Потому что так указано в спецификации, а ее стараются придерживаться ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Ну и в случае, если бы это были не геттеры/сеттеры тогда работа в том виде как есть сейчас была бы невозможно, так как это свойство описано в прототипе Object

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. К примеру, если присвоить не примитив, а obj.__proto__ =  obj2. , тогда __proto__ выступает в качестве сеттера и устанавливает новое значение?

Comment: в случае `obj.__proto__ =` proto всегда выступает в качестве сеттера, неважно что ты ему присваиваешь, так как это обычное свойство и когда его пишут слева от `=` оно setter, когда просто получают значение - getter

Comment: в принципе вообще не думай про это свойство `__proto__` - просто **НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗУЙ** его. Оно не рекомендовано к использованию.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Хочется разобраться в тонкостях просто. Все это очень интересно. Не буду использовать))

Comment: Это не тонкости, а тупо костыли ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score -1):

```js
function check(obj) {
  for (var x = obj; x; x = Object.getPrototypeOf(x)) {
    var d = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(x, "__proto__")
    
    if (d) {
      console.log(x === Object.prototype, d)
      return
    }
  }
  
  console.log("Not found")
}

check({})
check(Object.create(null))
check({ __proto__: {} })
check({ ["__proto__"]: {} })
check({ __proto__: null })
check({ get __proto__() { return 1 } })
check({ get __proto__() { return 1 }, set __proto__(v) {} })
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Comment: интересно, почему 3 и 4 варианты по разному работают

Comment: @Grundy, потому что security. Нельзя делать прототип вычисляемым свойством.

Comment: И за что минус? Прям точный ответ на заданный вопрос, всё работает, но нет, минус главное влепить.

Comment: потому что пустой блок кода, непонятно что показывающий :)

Comment: @Grundy, всё в консоли же.

Comment: Какая механика-то? :-D Я вижу что куча логов вывелась, они разные, но что они показывают, применительно к вопросу? :)

Comment: @Grundy, ну геттер и сеттер видно в дефинишене свойства, который выковыривает функция. Проверка, принадлежит ли этот дефинишен прототипу объекта тоже выводится через true или false. Ровно то, что просили в вопросе.

Comment: мне почему-то кажется, что в вопросе не это просили :)

Comment: @Grundy, ну тогда отвечай в соответствии с тем, как понимаешь вопрос. Я понимаю именно так, как ответил.

Comment: А я оценил.  :-)